# enable and disable a checkbox field after test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, validation-rule

I need help writing a formula for the following scenario:

I have 2 Checkbox fields on a custom Object: Approved_by_Manager__c and Bc_sent__c.

The test: if Approved_by_Manager__c is checked then Bc_sent__c is checkable else if Approved_by_Manager__c is not checked, then BC_Sent__c is not checkable, i.e., read only.

so I would like to insert a formula on validation rules on BC_sent__c:

> IF( Approved_by_Manager__c  = TRUE ,able, disable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to build a validation rule to restrict the field "Bc Sent" to be checked only if the "Approved By Manager" checkbox field is checked,

then you can simply use the below in the Validation Rule criteria

```
AND(NOT(Approved_by_Manager__c),Bc_Sent__c)
```

This is to say, if the approved by manager is not checked but if the Bc Sent checkbox is checked, then validation rule will fire and show the error back to the user

Note : you cannot enable / disable the checkbox field in standard page layout based on other checkbox.

This Validation rule can only restrict from checking this field based on the other checkbox field.

Comment: thank you so much !!  yes, that I would like to do .